# How do you best create a test database for API- testing?

Tags: sql-server, docker, express, web-api-testing

I'm creating a rest API using express.js whose purpose is interaction between a mssql database and a front-end. I'm curious about testing though, as I want to automatically test whether requests to the API give the right responses, using npm supertest. For this I want to create a copy of the database containing test-data, but optimally run the database locally when testing. Does this make sense? Or are there better ways of testing http requests and responses.

I've googled a lot, but I'm still very unsure. Maybe I have to create a docker container running the ms sql server, to which I would connect in the test, adding the correct tables and data before all tests? Maybe I can include SQL server as a dependency without docker, but I'm still quite new to all of this so I'm not sure.

Edit:
I have an express.js API which connects to a Microsoft SQL server database. I want to test the API using supertest with the Mocha framework. My thought process is when running the script 'npm test', the app should connect to an mssql database with the same structure as the prod database, that runs locally, and only contains test data. I'm not sure if this is the way to go, or if this is even possible with SQL server.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.